# Access event target in EaselJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, easeljs

I'm an EaselJS newbie. I'm running version 0.7.1. I have a simple game that generates tiles. I would like to remove those tiles whenever they are clicked on. I know my click handler is called for each click event, but my tiles aren't being removed. What am I doing wrong?

```
c99.Game = (function() {
    function Count99Game(){
        this.canvas = document.getElementById('game-canvas');

        this.stage = new createjs.Stage(this.canvas);
        var totalTiles = 10;

        for(var i = totalTiles; i>0; i--){
            var tile = new c99.Tile(i);
            this.stage.addChild(tile);

            tile.x = Math.random()*(this.canvas.width - tile.width);
            tile.y = Math.random()*(this.canvas.height - tile.height);

            tile.addEventListener("click", function(event){
                alert("Clicked");
                this.stage.removeChild(event.target);
                this.stage.update();
            }.bind(this));
        }       

        this.stage.update();
    }    
    return Count99Game;
})();
```

Comment: Does your tile have any child elements? You might try either using `event.currentTarget`, or making the tile have `mouseChildren=false`. Have you looked at what the `event.target` resolves to?

Comment: One other suggestion is to replace usages of `addEventListener` with the `on()` method, added in EaselJS 0.7.0. This provides a browser-safe scope parameter (as well as a "once" parameter, which might be handy in your example).

Comment: @Lanny: I updated my code to use on() and event.currentTarget. I'm not sure what you mean by "resolves" for event.target. Do you mean the return value. If so, then the return value is false. event.currentTarget returns a true value.

Comment: The `target` is what was clicked, whereas the `currentTarget` is what dispatched the event you are listening to. Both of these should be display objects. Note that prior to 0.7.0, there was no `currentTarget`, since there was no event bubbling.